# Word-break property does not work in Edge Browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have this working codepen https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/eYJEqRB?editors=1100

```
<div class='bubble'>
 <div class='parent'>
  <div class='text'>
   b vgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggvggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
  </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

```
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;

  color: hsl(165, 65%, 90%);
  border: 1px solid hsl(168, 74%, 48%);
  background-color: hsl(168, 74%, 48%);
  fill: hsl(165, 65%, 90%);

  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 24px 7px 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But the same exact code is not working on Edge browser (text gets cut). Does this make sense?

Comment: It's breaking fine on my version of Microsoft Edge. Which one are you using: the one running on Blink or Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, which exact version of the MS Edge browser you are using for making this test.

This is the test result with the MS Edge legacy browser (44.18362.449.0).

[image]

This is the test result with the MS Edge (Chromium) browser (83.0.478.58).

[image]

I suggest running this sample code directly in the Edge browser to check the result. It may help you to narrow down the issue.

If the issue persists then please try to provide detailed information with the snapshot of the issue can help us to understand the issue in a better way.